# Java mail api message id returns null in some cases

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

i have problem while reading mails from my mail account and save it in my database. My code is below:

```
    Store store = null;
    Folder folder = null;
    Message message = null;
    Message[] messages = null;
    Object messagecontentObject = null;
    String sender = null;
    String subject = null;
    Multipart multipart = null;
    Part part = null;
    String contentType = null;
    String dateTime = "";
    String fileName = "";
    Session session = null;
    int count = 0;

    try {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");

        session = Session.getInstance(System.getProperties(), null);
        store = session.getStore("imap");
        store.connect(mailserver, mail, password);

        folder = store.getDefaultFolder();
        folder = folder.getFolder("Inbox");
        folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

        messages = folder.getMessages();

        // UNREAD messages
        FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
        messages = folder.search(ft);

        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
             message = messages[i];
            subject = message.getSubject();
            String msgId[] =message.getHeader("Message-Id");// Problem  arise here
            System.out.println(msgId[0]);
            boolean flag = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
```

msgId returns null in some cases and i can't find solution for this problem.

Comment: I have the same problem and the header is definitely there. I can see it when I save the file as EML.

Answer (score 4):

Messages aren't **required** to have a Message-Id header.  Most do, and many servers will add one if they receive a message without one, but it's not impossible to encounter a message without such a header.  Often such messages are spam.

So, depending on what you're using the Message-Id value for, you're going to have to find another way to accomplish it.